# how to call the parameter in ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i need to call the parameter which i pass in web service to get the store procedure values in sql server, but i dnt knw hot to call

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ExecuteAJAXCall() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Name.asmx/GetUserDetails",
            data: "{'name':'" + $("#txtename").val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: Callback_AJAXCall
        });
    };

    function Callback_AJAXCall(data) {
        document.getElementById("DataContainer").innerHTML = "the result is: " +     data.d;
    };
 </script>
  </head>
      <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
    <h2>
        AJAX call test page</h2>
         <input type="text" id="txtname" />
    <button type="button" onclick="ExecuteAJAXCall()";>
        Getdetails</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="DataContainer">
    </div>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

pls check my code to pass parameter ,if i call like it shows the reult is null

Comment: What is output of `console.log(data)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public string GetUserDetails(string name)
    {
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("exec sp_n @name='" + name + "'", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_n";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    //XmlDataDocument xmldata = new XmlDataDocument(ds);
    //XmlElement xxx = xmldata.DocumentElement;
    return ds.GetXml();

    }
```

intially i didnt gave return ds.GetXml

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
function ExecuteAJAXCall() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Name.asmx/GetUserDetails",
                data: {name:$("#txtename").val()},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: Callback_AJAXCall
            });
        };
```

Comment: in function call ,am giving parameter like  data: "{'name':'" + $("#txtename").val() + "'}", whether is crt?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : as your data type is json then use `data[d]` to call your result data.

```
function Callback_AJAXCall(data) {
   document.getElementById("DataContainer").innerHTML = "the result is: "+data[d];
};
```

Comment: ,In that i just give alert("hi"); so here am getting alert box only, if i click alert box it shows run time error in data[d] , can u help me

Comment: try with `alert(data);` and check if `d` element is present in `data`

Comment: ,hmm but in web service am using xml element,here the store procedure values are loaded, but while coming to client side the result is shows ,,,,,,, like commas, help me pls

Comment: then try with `dataType: 'html'` and check `alert(data);`

Comment: See [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for ajax datatype. I think you are not getting response properly. Please debug your ajax url and check if data returning.

Comment: i dnt knw how to fetch the details from webservice, in my alert box it shows like ,,,,,,, commas